# Linear programming and shortest path

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

Given the linear programming formulation of the shortest path problem:
$$
\begin{align*}
\min & \sum_{u,v \in A} c_{uv} x_{uv}\\
\text{s.t } & \sum_{v \in V^{+}(s)} x_{sv} - \sum_{v \in V^{-}(s)}x_{vs} = 1\\
& \sum_{v \in V^{+}(u)} x_{uv} - \sum_{v \in V^{-}(u)}x_{vu} = 0 \quad \text{ for each } u \in V\setminus\{s,t\}\\
& \sum_{v \in V^{+}(t)} x_{tv} - \sum_{v \in V^{-}(t)}x_{vt} = -1\\
& x_{uv} \ge 0
\end{align*}
$$

I am asked to show that it provides an optimal integer solution by building a solution using the Dijkstra algorithm for both the primal and the dual with both solutions having the same value.

I have no troubles in finding the dual, however I am unclear about what exactly I have to do. In particular, how do I apply Dijkstra in finding a solution for the above program?

Comment: My initial thought would be to use the optimal substructure of the shortest path problem to iteratively compute a sequence of dual feasible solutions with a monotonically decreasing duality gap. I am a bit rusty on optimization though so this may be worded precisely.